# Is this possible to have additional fields or validation rules in package extension?

Tags: custom-metadata, managed-extension

I want to move some fields and some piece of functionality which we have developed but don't want to release yet to package extension.

But I have some both either with deployment to scratch org or with building a package.

I have two folders: `base` and `extension`. `Base` folder contains the base package and `extension` contains the metadata of the package extension.

If I have the file both in the base and extension folder like this

```
base/objects/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object
extension/objects/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object
```

extension package installation fails with an error

> 1. Cannot add component of type:CustomObject CustomMetadata__mdt
>    subjectId to another package because it is an installed component.,
>    Details: package.xml: Cannot add component of type:CustomObject
>    CustomMetadata__mdt subjectId to another package because it is an
>    installed component.

If I have only file in the base folder,

```
base/objects/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object
```

I receive an error when I try push the both codebase to my scratch org

```
{
  "fullName": "CustomMetadata__mdt",
  "type": "CustomObject",
  "state": "Failed",
  "error": "Must specify a non-empty label for the CustomObject",
  "problemType": "Error",
  "filePath": "/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object-meta.xml"
},
```

How can I make it to work both for the deployment of unpackaged metadata to a scratch org and installation of package extension when built?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with having two folders: `unpackaged` and `packaged`.

In the first folder I keep the source of truth for the code and I introduce the changes here and keep there two files

```
base/objects/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object
extension/objects/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object
```

.

When I build the package, I copy the sources from `unpackaged` to `packaged`, change `c` to `$namespace` where needed and remove the file

```
extension/objects/CustomMetadata__mdt/CustomMetadata__mdt.object
```

so that 2GMP extension is built with only fields or validation but without introducing a new copy of the custom metadata object itself.